# EditText with custom background turning red using TextInputLayout

Tags: android

I'm using an EditText with a drawable as background and a TextInputLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:hintEnabled="false">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_border"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/gray" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Every time there an error it looks like the error was clear

[image]

But when I touch the EditText (doesn't change the focus of the editText) again all the EditText becomes red

[image]

For setting the error and clear in the TextInputLayout I'm using

```
input_layout.setError(getResources().getString(id));
input_edittext.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
```

Do you have any idea how to solve it? When we don't use the background, it doesn't happen

Comment: Try to clean the error with `input_layour.setError(null);`

Comment: Actually, I was using OnTouchEvent and then applying setError

Comment: Remove android:background="@drawable/input_border" from EditText. This will solve your issue. In case you want to have a background for EditText, add background property to TextInputLayout